# Unable to display text from a double to a string

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having an issue with a simple app for iOS 9.

When I press the calculate button, the app closes and it will not change the text of the label.

What did I do wrong?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var weightTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var repsTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultsLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func calculateButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        let numberOfReps = Double(repsTextField.text!)!
        let weight = Double(weightTextField.text!)!

        let x = (numberOfReps * 0.033)
        let x1 = (x + 1)
        let max = (weight * x1)


        let oneMaxRepString = Double(max)

        resultsLabel.text = String(oneMaxRepString)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: UI]
[image: IBOutlets]
[image: Test]

@rogue-studios is right. You didn't connect `IBOutlets` correctly.

Comment: I tried adding a new label, named it something different, and still got the same results.  I press control, and click on the label and drag it over to the code.  This is how I've done all the test programs before this, so I am not sure what I have done wrong.

Comment: Am I putting the connection in the wrong place?  And, as always, thanks for your assistance.

Comment: If you create `Xib` file and `.swift` files seperately. You should `connect view` too. Please check the image and check your `view connection`. Still you can't find the problem, I suggest you to remove `xib-file/project` and add new one.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your code would work. Your app could be crashing because your connection between labels/buttons are not connected correctly. Go and make sure that your `@IBOutlets` are connected to the storyboard objects.

If this does not work, comment the error that you are getting in the console.

Comment: I deleted the project and started new.  The program, old and new, works until I get to